# How to get different high level touch gestures in WPF (C#/XAML)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, touch, gesture

I wanted to implement high level gestures like a circular gesture using a finger. Do I have to write the logic for it using ManipulationDelta and other basic touch gestures or is there any good dll which implements these? If there is any good resource, please provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [InkAnalyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ink.inkanalyzer.analyze%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) then you can detect the circle as the letter 'O'. InKAnalyzer has an Analyze method for Character and Handwriting recognition.